# Java Spring альтернативы JsonView передачи части модели на Frontend

Tags: java, json, spring, jackson

Я недавно начал постигать азы Java Spring и хотелось бы узнать, к каким методам прибегают разработчики для передачи на frontend части модели.

Например, в классе есть 2 поля - name и age. В одном методе контроллера я хочу отдать полный набор полей, в другом - только поле name.

На данный момент подобные вещи я реализую при помощи аннотации @JsonView.

Есть ли какие-то другие методы решения подобной задачи?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Другой подход - написание "кратких dto" и конвертеров "полное dto" -> "краткое dto". Упростить написание конвертеров можно с помощью специальных фреймворков, например, [MapStruct](https://mapstruct.org/) или Spring Conversion. Доклад по  по выбору фреймворка для конвертации типов данных можно глянуть [тут](https://2013.jokerconf.com/presentations/java_mapping_dlya_pragmatichnyh_programmistov_-_45_mins_-_joker.pdf)